# Best firewall for Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-9.10, firewall, ufw, firestarter

I currently have ufw and Firestarter installed on my Ubuntu Desktop 9.10

Which one should I stick with?

Comment: Please define "best" first! Why do you need a firewall at all? Does your desktop have a direct internet connection? What services do you run that have open ports?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both [**UFW**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncomplicated_Firewall) and [**Firestarter**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firestarter_%28firewall%29) are [**iptables**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iptables) based firewall frontends.
You should basically stick with the one you find comfortable and supports configurations you want to do.

Here is an [ArchLinux wiki page on Firewalls](http://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Firewalls) that compares both of these and a handful of others.
And a LinuxQuestions discussion: [confused about apparmor, **ufw** and **firestarter**](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/ubuntu-63/confused-about-apparmor-ufw-and-firestarter-769256/).

Answer (score 1):

I use UFW and change the default ports being used by the services like FTP and DNS.

Answer (score 1):

As commented by Manni, it really depends on how you intend to use your computer.

UFW and Firestarter are essentially front-ends to the same back-end (`iptables`). For a typical desktop use, I find that UFW is the easiest interface to use.

Atch... I see somebody else posted almost the same answer while I was typing! :-|